# Is there a "nice" way to advance a pointer to a struct by one byte?

Tags: c, lvalue, pointer-arithmetic

I have a pointer to a structure that I would like to move over an
address range, byte-by-byte. I have an approach that's working, but
it's ugly in my eyes. Unfortunately, the "nice" way doesn't work. Here's a minimum example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} s_t;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    uint32_t address = 17;
    s_t* ps = (s_t*) address;

    // ugly
    uint8_t* gna = (uint8_t*) ps;
    ++gna;
    ps = (s_t*) gna;

    // nice
    ++((uint8_t*) ps);
}
```

The compiler reports an error on the "nice" part:

```
% gcc test.c -o test.bin
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:17:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
     ++((uint8_t*) ps);
     ^
```

I understand the error, but I thought casting to an uint8_t* would
create an lvalue. Obviously, I'm wrong.

Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve by that - but this is very likely to result in unaligned memory access...

Comment: You already have a character pointer `gna`, why not just use that as intended? Incrementing a structure pointer by one byte is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense. If you were to increase the struct pointer by 1 byte, you would end up with a misaligned address, which would be problematic on most systems. I'll have to assume that your system is *not* any of the mainstream 32/64 bit CPUs (not x86, ARM, PowerPC etc) or otherwise your question makes no sense.

To increase the address by one byte, simply do this:

```
ps = (s_t*) ((uintptr_t)ps + 1);
```

Comment: It makes sense, but since it's not part of the problem, I didn't bother to elaborate. Thanks for the hint "uintptr_t" - I used it too rarely to remember...

Comment: @Markus The advantage of `uintptr_t` over `uint8_t` is that you won't get any unexpected pointer aliasing problems. If you convert a struct pointer to `uint8_t` pointer that's fine, but when you change that pointer the compiler no longer knows the "effective type" (variable type) of the data stored at that location. It will assume that the data is `uint8_t`. And then when you convert back to `s_t*` you get a strict pointer aliasing violation. If you won't cast back to `s_t*` then this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

As solution can be defining a `char*` pointer to point to the struct. Then by adding this pointer you could access to the bytes of the pointed structure.

```
 s_t a;
 unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*)&a;
 unsigned char next_byte = *(++b);
```

Then by adding `b` you can get the bytes of the `a`. The **shortage** of this solution is you might get error or warning in some compilers to pass the pointer to struct by a char pointer.

Comment: You *must* even see a diagnostic, assigning such a pointer is a constraint violation. But casting that pointer (in this special case) should do. With such a cast your solution is  fine, and *the* way to go to inspect every byte of the structure.

Comment: `unsigned char *b = &a;` is indeed not valid C. Change this to `unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*)&a;`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ps = (s_t*) (1 + (uint8_t*) ps);
```

Comment: I believe this will cause a strict aliasing violation since the compiler cannot know the effective type of the data stored at `1 + (uint8_t*) ps`. If it therefore assumes that the data is of `uint8_t` type, you get a strict aliasing violation when you try to access this as a struct.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the posted code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// for flexability, do not overlap the 'typedef' with the struct definition 
// (and always use a struct tag name)
typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} s_t;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) <-- causes 2 compiler warning messages 
// due to unused parameters
// suggest: int main( void )
{
    uint32_t address = 17;
    s_t* ps = (s_t*) address;  <-- 17 is not a valid address for a struct.

    // ugly   <-- however, it actually works
    uint8_t* gna = (uint8_t*) ps;
    ++gna;
    ps = (s_t*) gna; <-- don't do this, 
    // use 'gna' to access the individual bytes

    // nice
    ++((uint8_t*) ps); <-- does not compile
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Obviously type casting such as `(uint8_t*)` doesn't result in an lvalue. Since your code is in C++, you may use this casting `(uint8_t*&)`.